# Can't seem to call function correctly in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference

EDIT: Thank you everyone for taking the time to answer. I tried everyone's suggestions one by one and it still didn't work. I really wanted to hand this in without having to ask the professor for help and show I couldn't figure out how to do it, but at this point, I guess I'll have to do just that. I appreciate you taking the time to help! Thank you.

I'm taking a C++ course and have an assignment I am having trouble with. I keep getting the error: "expected primary-expression before 'int'" by all three array declarations. And "was not declared in this scope" by all three passing addresses. This is on the compiler I usually use. I tried a different compiler, and the error I got was "prog.cpp:14:38: error: cannot convert 'std::array*' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void addArrays(int*, int*, int*)'
     addArrays(&array1,&array2,&array3);"
I'm not really sure what's going on, as I'm a beginner and was hoping someone could tell me what those errors mean and what I can do to fix them. Thank you in advance. Here is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
void addArrays(int*, int*, int*);

int main()
{
    array< int, 20 >array1 = 
        {7,45,90,1,33,254,3,8,9,4,2,6,77,5,9,2,22,4,12,6};
    array< int, 20 >array2 =
        {88,4,6,75,1,12,33,99,66,88,7,4,44,4,3,13,5,4,9,3};
    array< int, 20 >array3;

    addArrays(&array1,&array2,&array3);   

    cout << "Array1 + Array2 = Array3" << endl;
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<20; ++j)
        cout << array1[j] << "+" << array2[j] << "=" << array3[j] << endl;

    return 0;
}

void addArrays(int *array1, int *array2, int *array3)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<20; ++i) 
        array3[i] = array1[i]+array2[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the function to remain `void addArrays(int *array1, int *array2, int *array3)` You can use the `data` method of `std::array`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
void addArrays(int*, int*, int*);

int main()
{
    array< int, 20 >array1 = 
        {7,45,90,1,33,254,3,8,9,4,2,6,77,5,9,2,22,4,12,6};
    array< int, 20 >array2 =
        {88,4,6,75,1,12,33,99,66,88,7,4,44,4,3,13,5,4,9,3};
    array< int, 20 >array3;

    addArrays(array1.data(),array2.data(),array3.data());   

    cout << "Array1 + Array2 = Array3" << endl;
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<20; ++j)
        cout << array1[j] << "+" << array2[j] << "=" << array3[j] << endl;

    return 0;
}

void addArrays(int *array1, int *array2, int *array3)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<20; ++i) 
        array3[i] = array1[i]+array2[i];
}
```

Or make the function take `std::array`s as arguments like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
void addArrays(const array<int,20> &array1, 
                    const array<int,20> &array2,
                    array<int,20> &array3);
int main()
{
    array< int, 20 >array1 = 
        {7,45,90,1,33,254,3,8,9,4,2,6,77,5,9,2,22,4,12,6};
    array< int, 20 >array2 =
        {88,4,6,75,1,12,33,99,66,88,7,4,44,4,3,13,5,4,9,3};
    array< int, 20 >array3;

    addArrays(array1,array2,array3);   

    cout << "Array1 + Array2 = Array3" << endl;
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<20; ++j)
        cout << array1[j] << "+" << array2[j] << "=" << array3[j] << endl;

    return 0;
}

void addArrays(const array<int,20> &array1, 
                    const array<int,20> &array2,
                    array<int,20> &array3)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<20; ++i) 
        array3[i] = array1[i]+array2[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function declaration like

```
void addArrays( const std::array<int. 20> &, 
                const std::array<int, 20> &, 
                std::array<int, 20> &);
```

and call it like

```
addArrays( array1, array2, array3 );
```

Another approach is to declare the function as is

```
void addArrays( const int *, const int *, int * );
```

but call it like

```
addArrays( array1.data(), array2.data(), array3.data() );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following signature

```
addArrays(int*, int*, int*);
```

does not take an std:array -- it compiles if you change it to

```
void addArrays(array< int, 20 > *array1, array< int, 20 > *array2, array< int, 20 > *array3)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<20; ++i) 
        (*array3)[i] = (*array1)[i]+(*array2)[i];
}
```

if you change the prototype to

```
void addArrays(array< int, 20 > &array1, array< int, 20 > &array2, ......)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function expecting `int*` and you are passing `array<int,20>*`.

Try this.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <array>
using namespace std;
void addArrays( array< int, 20 >&,  array< int, 20 >&,  array< int, 20 >&);

int main()
{
    array< int, 20 >array1 = 
        {7,45,90,1,33,254,3,8,9,4,2,6,77,5,9,2,22,4,12,6};
    array< int, 20 >array2 =
        {88,4,6,75,1,12,33,99,66,88,7,4,44,4,3,13,5,4,9,3};
    array< int, 20 >array3;

    addArrays(array1,array2,array3);   

    cout << "Array1 + Array2 = Array3" << endl;
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<20; ++j)
        cout << array1[j] << "+" << array2[j] << "=" << array3[j] << endl;

    return 0;
}

void addArrays(array< int, 20 >& array1,  array< int, 20 >& array2,  array< int, 20 >& array3)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<20; ++i) 
        array3[i] = array1[i]+array2[i];
}
```